# If $T$ is a homeomorphism and $\Omega$ is a closed set which is invariant under $T$, then $T(\Omega)=\Omega$

Tags: general-topology, differential-topology, diffeomorphism

Let $d\in\mathbb N$, $T$ be a homeomorphism from $\mathbb R^d$ onto $\mathbb R^d$ and $\Omega\subseteq\mathbb R^d$ be closed awith  $T(\Omega)\subseteq\Omega$.

Assuming that $\Omega=\partial M$ for some $d$-dimensional properly embedded, [Jack Lee](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/1421/jack-lee) showed in [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/370453/91890) that $T(\Omega)=\Omega$.

However, it's not apparent to me at which point of his argumentation we actually need that $\Omega$ is of this particular form and not just any closed subset of $\mathbb R^d$ which is invariant under $T$.

In the first part, he is assuming that $\Omega$ is connected. The idea is to use the fact that [a connected set has no proper clopen subset](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Connected_iff_no_Proper_Clopen_Sets). Since $T$ is a homeomorphism and $\Omega$ is $\mathbb R^d$-closed, it is clear to me that $T(\Omega)$ is $\mathbb R^d$-closed and hence (since $T(\Omega)=T(\Omega)\cap\Omega$) $\Omega$-closed.

While it is also clear to me that $\left.T\right|_\Omega$ is a homeomorphism from $\Omega$ to $T(\Omega)$ and hence an open map, it is not clear to me how he's concluding that $T(\Omega)$ is $\Omega$-open. The fact that $\left.T\right|_\Omega$ is a homeomorphism from $\Omega$ to $T(\Omega)$ should only yield that $T(\Omega)$ is $T(\Omega)$-open, which is a triviality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take $T(x)=x/2$ on $\mathbb{R}$, take $\Omega=[-1, 1]$. Then $T\Omega \subsetneq \Omega$.

In the situation of that question the fact that $T$ is diffeomorphism onto its image shows that it's an open map from $\Omega$ to $\Omega$. (For manifolds of same dimension, the inverse function theorem tells you that diffeomorphic image of an open set is open: given $p$ and $T(p)$, some neighborhood of $p$ is mapped homeomorphically to some neighborhood of $T(p)$, hence the image under $T$ of an open set is open).  Here there is no such property, $T$ is not an open map from $\Omega$ to itself.

Comment: Ah, for a general homeomorphism $T$ from $\Omega$ to $T(\Omega)$ it does only hold that $T$ is an open map from $\Omega$ to $T(\Omega)$. That's clear to me. Did I get you right that if such a $T$ is even a diffeomorphism, it is even an open from $\Omega$ to $\Omega$? Or do  we really need that $\Omega$ is manifold?

Comment: For any reasonable definition of "diffeomоrphism" that applies to non-manifolds the map in this example is a diffeomorphism from $\Omega$ to $T\Omega$. You really need $\Omega$ to be a manifold.

Comment: My definition of diffeomorphism is that if $E_i$ is a Banach space, $B_1\subseteq E_1$ and $f:B_1\to E_2$, then $f$ is $C^1$-differentiable if for all $x\in B_1$ there is an $E_1$-open neighborhood $O_1$ of $x$ with $\left.f\right|_{B_1\:\cap\:O_1}=\left.\tilde f\right|_{B_1\:\cap\:O_1}$ for some $\tilde f\in C^1(O,E_2)$. $f$ is a $C^1$-diffeomorphism if it is bijective and $f$ and $f^{-1}$ are both $C^1$-differentiable.

Comment: BTW, if you write $\Omega$ in your last paragraph, do you really mean the particular $\Omega$, i.e. $\Omega=\partial M$, which I mentioned in the question? If that's the case, please note that $\partial M$ is $\mathbb R^d$-closed, but it seems like your inverse function theorem argument needs $\Omega$ to be $\mathbb R^d$-open.

Comment: In the last paragraph I apply the inverse function theorem to $\Omega$, NOT to the ambient space. (More precisely: if $\Omega$ is a finite dimensional manifold, there are charts $\psi_p$ and $\psi_{T(p)}$ taking  neighborhoods of $p$ and $T(p)$  in $\Omega$   resp. to open subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$; we apply the IFT to $\psi_{T(p)} \cdot T \cdot \psi_p^{-1}$ restricted to small neighborhood of $\psi_p(p)$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: I still can't follow and I'm unsure whether we are using the same assumptions. To avoid any misunderstandings, let $M$ be a $k$-dimensional embedded $C^1$-submanifold of $\mathbb R^d$ **without** boundary and $\Omega$ be an open subset of $M$. Our goal is to show that $\Omega':=T(\Omega)$ is $\mathbb R^d$-open. By definition of a submanifold, there is a $C^1$-diffeomorphism $\phi$ from $\Omega$ onto $U:=\phi(\Omega)$. And $\psi:=\phi\circ\left.T^{-1}\right|_{\Omega'}$ is a $C^1$-diffeomorphism from $\Omega'$ onto $U$. Now you want to apply the IFT to $\psi\circ T\circ\phi^{-1}$.

Comment: Let $x\in\Omega$ and $u:=\phi(x)$. Then the IFT yields that there is an $\mathbb R^k$-open neighborhood $U_u\subseteq U$ of $u$ and an $\mathbb R^k$-open neighborhood $V_u$ of $(\psi\circ T\circ\phi^{-1})(u)=u$ such that $\left.\psi\circ T\circ\phi^{-1}\right|_{U_u}$ is a $C^1$-diffeomorphism. How do we obtain that $\Omega'$ is $\mathbb R^k$-open from that?

Comment: Our goal is to show that $T\Omega$ is open in $M$ (NOT in $\mathbb{R}^d$, that would be false).  We have $T\circ \phi^{-1}(U_u)$ is open neighborhood of $T(p)$ in $M$; thus $T\Omega$ contains neighborhood of $T(p)$; since $p$ was arbitrary point of $\Omega$, $T\Omega$ is open.

Comment: You're right, we need to show that $\Omega'$ is $M$-open. That was a typo. But from what in the IFT do you conclude that $T\circ\phi^{-1}(U_u)$ is an $M$-open neighborhood of $T(x)$?

Comment: Maybe you can clarify your notation in your second comment. From what I understand, your $\psi_p$ is my $\phi$ and your $\psi_{T(p)}$ is my $\psi$. But in that case, this doesn't make much sense to me, since $\psi\circ T\circ\phi^{-1}=\operatorname{id}_U$.

Comment: $\psi_p$ is a manifold chart around $p$ and $\psi_{T(p)}$ is a manifold chart around $T(p)$ (the manifold being $M$). The composition $\psi_{T(p)} \circ  T \circ \psi_p^{-1}$  is the $T$ as expressed in those coordinates. It is most likely NOT identity.

Comment: I think I figured it out: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3849654/47771. Maybe you can take a look.