# Is the restriction of a diffeomorphism to a manifold $M$ an open map from $M$ to $M$?

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, manifolds-with-boundary, diffeomorphism

Let $d\in\mathbb N$, $k\in\{1,\ldots,d\}$, $M$ be a $k$-dimenional embedded $C^1$-submanifold of $\mathbb R^d$ with boundary, $T$ be a $C^1$-diffeomorphism of $\mathbb R^d$ onto $\mathbb R^d$ and $N:=T(M)$.

We know that [the restriction of a homeomorphism is a homeomorphism](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Restriction_of_Homeomorphism_is_Homeomorphism) and hence $\left.T\right|_M$ is a homeomorphism of $M$ onto $N$. In particular, $T$ is an open map from $M$ to $N$.

> **Question 1**: Assuming $T(M)\subseteq M$, are we even able to show that $\left.T\right|_M$ is an open map from $M$ to $M$?
>
> **Question 2**: In the same spirit, are we able to show $\left.T\right|_{\partial M}$ is an open map from $\partial M$ to $\partial M$?

Comment: $T: M \rightarrow M$ induces tangent maps directly from the tangent maps of $T:\mathbb{R}^d \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^d$, which are isomorphisms, so $T$ is a local C^1-diffeomorphism, so in particular it’s open. By considering tangent spaces $T$ must map $\partial M$ to $\partial M$ and with the same argument $T$ is open there as well.

Comment: @Mindlack I can't follow (and I don't know what a "tangent map" is; please clarify). However, maybe you mean the following: It's clear to me that $\left.T\right|_M$ is a $C^1$-diffeomorphism from $M$ onto $N:=T(M)$ and hence we know that the pushforward ${\rm D}\left.T\right|_M(x)=\left.{\rm D}T(x)\right|_{T_x\:M}$ is an isomorphism from $T_x\:aM$ onto $T_{T(x)}\:N$ for all $x\in M$. But I don't see how we conclude that $\left.T\right|_M$ is an open map from $M$ to $M$.

Comment: It's an application of the inverse function theorem.

Comment: The tangent map of $f$ at $x$ is the induced map $T_x M \rightarrow T_{f(x)} N$ (if $f(M) \subset N$ with $N$ a manifold).

Comment: @DanielH.Hartman Could you elaborate on how the inverse function theorem is applied?

Comment: @Mindlack So, it's the map induced by the pushforward of $f$ at $x$, right? But you didn't reply to the rest of my comment. Why is $\left.T\right|_M$ an open map from $M$ to $M$?

Comment: That’s a good way to see it, I think. As per openness, that can be checked in a chart. The function has invertible differentials so (by the inverse function theorem) has local inverses, hence is locally open, hence open.

Comment: @Mindlack I still don't get it. Please take a look at the discussion below [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3845914/47771).

Comment: Right... This makes the map open when you restrict it to $M$ minus its boundary (and thus, it works for $\partial M$ if $T$ maps it into itself). I still can’t understand what step in the reasoning invertible tangent map/pushforward on tangent spaces -> (inverse function theorem) -> local diffeomorphism -> local openness is an issue to you.

Comment: @Mindlack I'm sorry, I'm sure it's trivial, but it's not even clear to me to which function you exactly intend to apply the inverse function theorem. Assume, for simplicity, that $\partial M=\emptyset$. Let $\Omega$ be an open subset of $M$ and $\phi$ be a $C^1$-diffeomorphism from $\Omega$ onto the $\mathbb R^k$-open set $U:=\phi(\Omega)$.

Comment: @Mindlack Let $x\in\Omega$ and $u:=\phi(x)$. We need to show that $T(x)$ is an interior point of $M$. What we already know is that $T(x)$ is an interior point of $N=T(M)$ (since $T$ is continuous from $\Omega$ to $\Omega':=T(\Omega)$.) I know that $\psi:=\phi\circ\left.T^{-1}\right|_{\Omega'}$ is a $C^1$-diffeomorphism from $\Omega'$ to $U$. To which function do you need apply the IFT now?

Comment: Let $x \in W \subset M$ for some open subset $W$ of $M$, $y=T(x) \in M$. There are open subsets $x \in U \subset W$, $T(U) \subset V$ of $M$ and diffeomorphisms $\alpha: \mathbb{R}^d \rightarrow U$ mapping $0$ to $x$, and $\beta: V \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^d$ with $\beta(y)=0$. Let $T_1=\beta \circ T \circ \alpha: \mathbb{R}^d \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^d$; it is a $C^1$ function mapping zero to itself with invertible derivative, so, by the IFT applied to $T_1$, $T_1(\mathbb{R}^d)$ is a neighborhood of zero. Thus $T(W) \supset \beta^{-1}(T_1(\mathbb{R}^d))$ is a neighborhood of $\beta^{-1}(0)=y$.

Comment: @Mindlack I think I figured it out: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3849654/47771. Maybe you can take a look.

Comment: I glanced at it – it looks like what I’ve been writing. Congrats for figuring it out!

Comment: @Mindlack In order to obtain the claim in the question, we still need to apply this version of the inverse function theorem. Please take a look at the [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3849822/47771) I've provided below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the symbol $T$ is usually used for the pushforward and tangent space, let me replace it by $f$.

We need to assume that $\partial M=\emptyset$.

Now let $\Omega$ be an open subset of $M$. We need to show that $\Omega':=f(\Omega)$ is $M$-open. Let $x\in\Omega$. By assumption, $\Omega'\subseteq f(M)\subseteq M$ and hence $$T_{f(x)}\:\Omega'\subseteq T_{f(x)}\:M\tag1.$$ Since $f$ is a $C^1$-diffeomorphism, $\Omega'$ is a $k$-dimensional $C^1$-submanifold of $\mathbb R^d$ as well and hence $$\dim T_{f(x)}\:\Omega'=k=\dim T_{f(x)}\:M\tag2.$$ So, $(1)$ is actually an equality. Since $\left.f\right|_\Omega$ is a $C^1$-diffeomorphism from $\Omega$ onto $\Omega'$, this implies that $T_x(\left.f\right|_\Omega)$ is an isomorphism from $T_x\:\Omega$ onto $T_{f(x)}\:\Omega'=T_{f(x)}\:M$. From [a version of the inverse function theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3849654/47771), we can infer that $\left.f\right|_{\tilde\Omega}$ is a $C^1$-diffeomorphism from $\tilde\Omega$ onto $\tilde\Omega':=f(\tilde\Omega)$ for some $\Omega$-open neighborhood $\tilde\Omega$ of $x$ and $\tilde\Omega'$ is an $M$-open neighborhood of $f(x)$. By construction, $$\tilde\Omega'\subseteq\Omega'\tag3.$$ Since $x$ was arbitary, $\Omega'$ is $M$-open and hence we have shown that $\left.f\right|_M$ is an open map from $M$ to $M$.