# If $T_t$ is a flow and $M$ is a manifold with $T_t(\partial M)⊆\partial M$ for all $t$, we've already got $T_t(\partial M)=\partial M$ for all $t$

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, manifolds-with-boundary, submanifold

Let $d\in\mathbb N$, $k\in\{1,\ldots,d\}$, $M$ be a $k$-dimensional embedded $C^1$-submanifold of $\mathbb R^d$ with boundary and $f$ be a $C^1$-diffeomorphism from $\mathbb R^d$ onto $\mathbb R^d$ with $f(\partial M)\subseteq\partial M$.

> Assume $\partial M$ is closed in $\mathbb R^d$.$^1$ How can we show that $f(\partial M)=\partial M$?

First of all, since $f$ is a homeomorphism from $\mathbb R^d$ onto $\mathbb R^d$ and $\partial M$ is closed in $\mathbb R^d$, we know that $f(\partial M)$ is closed in $\mathbb R^d$ and hence (since $f(\partial M)\subseteq\partial M$) closed in $\partial M$. On the other hand, again since $f(\partial M)\subseteq\partial M$, [we can show](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3849822/47771) that $\left.f\right|_{\partial M}$ is an open map from $\partial M$ to $\partial M$ and hence $f(\partial M)$ is open in $\partial M$.

> Since we have shown that $f(\partial M)$ is "clopen" in $\partial M$, the claim is immediate if $\partial M$ is connected. According to [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/370453/91890), this is enough to conclude, since we can consider the "connected components" of $\partial M$ separately. What's precisely meant by that and how can show this rigorously?

### **EDIT**

I actually don't need to show the claim (which is wrong, as [Lee Mosher](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/26501/lee-mosher) has shown in [his answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3851380/47771)) for an arbitrary $f$. If $\tau>0$ and $v:[0,\tau]\times\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ is continuous in the first argument and satisfies $$\sup_{t\in[0,\:\tau]}\left|v(t,x)-v(t,y)\right|\le c|x-y|\tag1$$ for some $c\ge0$, we know that, for all $x\in\mathbb R$, there is an unique $X^x\in C^0([0,\tau])$ with $$T_t(x):=X^x(t)=x+\int_0^tv(s,X^x(s))\:{\rm d}s\;\;\;\text{for all }t\in[0,\tau]\tag2.$$

> I want to show that $T_t(\partial M)\subseteq\partial M)$ for all $t\in[0,\tau]$ already implies $T_t(\partial M)=\partial M)$ for all $t\in[0,\tau]$.

---

$^1$ This is, for example, the case when $M$ is a $d$-dimensional properly embedded $C^1$-submanifold of $\mathbb R^d$ with boundary, since then $\partial M$ coincides with the topological boundary of $M$. I actually wonder whether it's possible at all that $\partial M$ is closed in $\mathbb R^d$ if $k<d$. So, **it would be great if someone could comment on that**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Lee Mosher pointed out, this is only true for flows, not for arbitrary diffeomorphisms.

Suppose $T_t$ is a global flow. Let $\partial_i M$ be an arbitrary connected component of $\partial M$. Choosing an arbitrary point $x_0\in \partial_i M$, the set $\{T_t(x_0): t\in [0,\tau]\}$ is a connected subset of $\partial M$, so it is contained in a single component. But when $t=0$, $T_t(x_0)=x_0\in \partial_i M$, so that component must be $\partial_i M$ itself.

Now for each $t\in [0,\tau]$, $T_t(\partial_i M)$ is a connected subset of $\partial M$ that has a point in common with $\partial_i M$, so it must be contained in $\partial_i M$. Then the open-closed argument you summarized shows that $T_t(\partial_i M) = \partial_i M$.

Now do you see why it matters that we're talking about a flow and not just an arbitrary diffeomorphism?

Comment: Is it (diffeomorphisms) true for smooth manifold? and connected?

Comment: @C.F.G: Can you state more precisely what you're asking?

Comment: Please clarify: What is your definition of a "connected component of $\partial M$" and what are you denoting by $\partial_{\color{red}i}M$?

Comment: @0xbadf00d: $\partial M$ is a topological space (with the subspace topology). A [connected component](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_space#Connected_components) of a topological space is a maximal connected subset. As I wrote in my answer, $\partial_i M$ just denotes an arbitrary connected component of $\partial M$.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Okay, I see, the image of a conencted set under a continuous function is connected. I think I got the point that $T_t(\partial_iM)\subseteq\partial_iM$ for all $t$. But now you are using the open-closed argument which I gave for the boundary $\partial M$ of the submanifold $M$; you're applying it to the connected component $\partial_iM$. Why can we do this? It seems like you're treating $\partial_iM$ as it would be the manifold boundary of some submanifold. Is this the case?

Comment: @JackLee: $f(\partial M)=\partial f(M)$? $f$ a diffeomorphism.

Comment: @C.F.G: This is a different question from the one the OP asked, which was whether $f(\partial M)=\partial M$. It's always true that $f(\partial M) = \partial f(M)$, even if $f$ is just a homeomorphism from $\mathbb R^d$ (or any topological space) to itself and $M$ is an arbitrary subset. It's just a basic topological fact, which has nothing to do with smoothness or flows or connectedness.

Comment: @0xbadf00d: No, I'm just treating $\partial_i M$ as a connected manifold in its own right. The restriction of $T_t$ to $\partial_i M$ is a smooth map from $\partial_i M$ to itself that is both open and closed. Such a map must be surjective.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a counterexample:

1. $k=d=1$
2. $M=\bigcup_{i=0}^\infty \,\, [i,i+\frac{1}{2}]$
3. $f(x)=x+1$

The context of [this linked answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/370453/91890) is different: it is about flows; whereas your question is about diffeomorphisms.

Comment: At which point is it important that we have a flow?

Comment: I hope that you don't mind that I've edited the question accordingly. Your answer is still useful on its own. I only need the claim for the flow case, but I didn't thought it would be crucial here. I guess it's somehow important that the inclusion relation holds on a nontrivial interval.